# Как записывать и распозновать речь с определенным промежутком?

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Есть такой вот код где для записи используется pyaudio возможно ли записывать только 15 секунд

```
import speech_recognition as sr



word_cnt = 1 #так как считаем кол-во проблелов,а последнего пробела нет
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index = 0)
r = sr.Recognizer()

with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print("done")

try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio,language='ru-RU')
    print (text)

except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Не понял")
    
except sr.RequestError:
    print("Нет ответа от серверов гуугла".format(e))


#for i in range(len(text)):
#    if text[i] == ' ':
#        word_cnt += 1
#print(word_cnt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst) вроде бы можно задать такой параметр:

```
r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=15)
```